# Will HTTPS slow down page loads of my web application?

Tags: performance, ssl, https, pageload

Will SSL Encryption slow down page load? If so, how do I estimate the impact on performance for my web application?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How much overhead does SSL impose?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/548029/how-much-overhead-does-ssl-impose)

Comment: I measured Mitch Wheat's answer for level of constructiveness. 0% result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a possible duplicate of several questions:

- [What is the overhead of using HTTPS compared to HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1892347/what-is-the-overhead-of-using-https-compared-to-http)
- [HTTP vs HTTPS performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/149274/http-vs-https-performance)
- [How much overhead does SSL impose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548029/how-much-overhead-does-ssl-impose)

The last includes [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/548042/751158), including:  "non-SSL sockets are less than 10 times faster than SSL sockets".  However, this can be a bit misleading - be sure to read the entire answer.

You can also mitigate the performance concern, at least on the server-side, by offloading the SSL processing to another device, e.g. a dedicated load balancer or firewall.